# Apache htaccess Redirect Catch All

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following rule as a catch all to redirect all requests to a new domain:

> RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

What I have found is that this works for a lot of requests but not all, for example:

> olddomain.com/web/search.php?region_id=1&this=that

What can I use to catch all requests and redirect them to the new domain?

Comment: How do you know it is not working for `olddomain.com/web/search.php?region_id=1&this=that`? Where is this .htaccess located in old domain?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) instead of mod_rewrite:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.example.com/
```

mod_rewrite is much more flexible, but mod_alias is very simple for cases like this.   It will redirect all pages on your old site to the new site with URL path and query string intact.

Comment: If I use that it appends anything after / to the new domain which I do not want.